# Can you please provide ideas on data implementation for testing an application?

Tags: database, mocking

I am testing a 3 yr old application with a bunch of data, since the data keeps changing I don't want to use the prod data. What other alternatives can I use to mimic the data or is it wise to just use the prod db in a test environment. Any comments or suggestions are welcomed :). If this is a repeated question my apologies but I will appreciate if you could guide me to the appropriate thread. Thanks

Comment: If you don't plan to model data with your program, I think it is save to use the current data in a test environment to make sure not deleting anything.

Comment: thanks for the comment @drmariod, I am leaning towards that option too but since the current data is changing everyday, I will have to keep modifying my automated tests in order to cope with the changing data :(

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have your database interaction code abstracted from your application, it will not be possible to mock it. Even then, it will depend on your implementation.

Within our environment, when a component makes use of a database, we include the database project within the solution. This database project has the ability to selectively deploy test data. When the component is deployed anywhere but production, the database is created and the test data is deployed. That way you have static, testable data that you can run your unit tests from.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ChrisBint, I should have mentioned this is for running my automated tests and not unit tests.

Comment: The same approach can be used for automated testing as well, you just need to ensure that the database/reference data is deployed to your test environment. We have a build/deploy workflow that deals with this automatically and will install the component (MSI) and database/data (DACPAC) automatically. We can then run our suite of automated tests against this single component, or the system as a whole  before allowing more granular system testing by real people.